# Reading and interpreting Serial information

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi to control a ESC and for that I am sending the instructions for the ESC using serial. My problem is that when i send the instructions i can not interoperate them, and by interoperate I mean check what the first letter is and then remove it and make the Arduino output a PWM signal. My problem is when I use the serial monitor to send an instruction it firstly comes up on several lines, and when I try and look at the first letter of the string the if statement thinks it is true for all inputs of "FirstLetter" my function to get the serial input it

```
String readSerial()
{
  char SerialInput;
  String Data = "";
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    SerialInput = Serial.read();
    Data.concat(SerialInput);
    //Serial.println(Data);
  }
  return Data;
}
```

the function that should interoperate  the information from readSerial() is

```
void DecodeInput()
{
  String input = readSerial();
  if (input != "")
  {
    char FirstLetter = input.charAt(1);
    if (FirstLetter = 'U')
    {
      Serial.println("Hello World");
      //input.setCharAt[0, '');
      //SetPower('U', Power);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things immediately jump out at me:

```
char FirstLetter = input.charAt(1);
```

charAt(1) is the *second* letter, not the first - the first is charAt(0).

```
if (FirstLetter = 'U')
```

That is saying "If I have been successful in assigning the value 'U' to FirstLetter then..." - "=" is assignment, you need "==" for comparison.

Also your `readSerial()` function is complete junk.  It's not doing anything at all like you think it is.  You should read this to better understand Arduino serial reading: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/reading-serial-on-the-arduino

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Firmata protocol, and not re-invent the wheel. Although doing so (re-inventing the wheel) is a good learning exercise, so is understanding something already written.

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Firmata

Then move on to the [cool stuff](http://cylonjs.com/) that uses it.

[image]